# $_POST returning null on server, but works fine on mamp localhost

Tags: php, html, apache

Hello everyone,

I'm a Newbie web app developer. Recently, I finished my project on Mamp 
  and trying to move everything into server. Then odd things happened. The $_POST 
  function all of sudden does not work.

I googled this question for two days and tried many things. Like 
 changing apache config, reinstall some php package. I tried to use  .htaccess, but did not figure out how it works. I just wondering is there 
    any other way to make this thing works as i tested on mamp.

By the way,i use LAMP in server.

Here is php code. var_dump($_POST) will return null and 
 var_dump($_REQUEST) will return array{}.

```
   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 
  $ID=$_POST['Client_ID'];
  $name=$_POST['username'];
  var_dump($_POST);
  $sex=$_POST['sex'];
  $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $time=$_POST['time'];
  $company_name=$_POST['Company_name'];
  $wechat_id=$_POST['Wechat_id'];

  if ($sex==0){
    $sex="female";
  } else {
   $sex="male";
  }
  $delOrnot=0;




  $sql="INSERT INTO Client(client_id,owner_name,gender,cell_phone,email,time,company_name,delOrnot,department) VALUES ('{$ID}','{$name}','{$sex}','{$mobile}','{$email}','{$time}','{$company_name}','{$delOrnot}','{$wechat_id}')";


if($conn->multi_query($sql)===TRUE){
     echo"New records created successfully";

  }else {
    echo "Error " . $sql . "<br>"  . $conn->error;
    }
  $conn->close();
```

Here is html code.

```
<form action="member-add.php" method="post" class="form form-horizontal" id="form-member-add">
    <div class="row cl">
        <label class="form-label col-xs-4 col-sm-3"><span class="c-red">*</span>userID：</label>
        <div class="formControls col-xs-8 col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="input-text" value="" placeholder="" id="Client_ID" name="Client_ID">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row cl">
        <label class="form-label col-xs-4 col-sm-3"><span class="c-red">*</span>username：</label>
        <div class="formControls col-xs-8 col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="input-text" value="" placeholder="" id="username" name="username">
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

And it works perfectly on mamp.  I don't know what is wrong on my server configurations. Thank you for your kindly help!

Comment: var_dump($_POST); its case sensitive

Comment: Oh, that is my mistype when i changed to var_dump($_POST) . it returns array(0) { }. Thanks for your remind!

Comment: then its most likely that either you overwrite $_POST somewhere or your form isnt submitted in normal way. check var_dump at the TOP of the php file, before you do anything else

Comment: Is the form closed `</form>` ?

Comment: @vivek_23 Yes, this is only part of the code.

Comment: @Kapsonfire I Checked the html header it seems ok about the submission.  The weird thing is it work perfectly on mamp. And $_POST are at the top of the code since i need to submit it into database and that is all member-add.php does.

Comment: ok, can you share entire `member-add.php` file?

Comment: @vivek_23 done.

Comment: Hi! Can you send all your form in HTML? (For example: I don't see submit button)

Comment: @xianhuichen still var_dump($_Post); instead of `var_dump($_POST);` ?

Comment: @vivek_23 Oh, forgot that part. this is copied from my local file. The server version is POST

Comment: @xianhuichen I really don't see any issue. This should give you `$_POST` values properly.

Comment: Okay, Thank you for your help. I will keep debugging this thing. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form opening tag

```
<form action="member-add.php" method="post" class="form form-horizontal" id="form-member-add">
```

Try adding an enctype, this attribute specifies how the form-data should be encoded when submitting it to the server.

```
<form action="member-add.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form form-horizontal" id="form-member-add">
```

This is how it should look. 
You can read more about the different enctypes [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp).

**How to debug this**
I think however that its more important to see, a possible way to debug this. When you make a request to the server, that request is sent and you can view, what you have sent to the server as well as the servers response. In order to do that (Chrome is used for this example), open your google developer tools (just press F12), then go to Networking and click on the request that its made when you click the send button.

Comment: I don't feel missing `enctype` is the issue here. `enctype` is generally used when there is a file upload.

Comment: @vivek_23 that is why I included the part about debuging, he/she can check what it is send to the server :)

Comment: @thefolenangel Thank you for the information! I will try it out.

Answer (score -1):

Is your php and HTML code is on same file?
I will suggest you to put your code at top of the file then check var_dump.

Comment: dont answer if you still ask a question, you can use `add a comment`

Comment: Yes, they are all under the /www that is how i upload them

Comment: @xianhuichen you need to put all under `public_html`(if it exists) probably?

Comment: @vivek_23  I dont get what you mean. I need to put everything under another html folder  under /www ?

Comment: @xianhuichen are you using a hosting provider or trying this on localhost?

Comment: @vivek_23 works perfectly on mamp localhost.  It doesnt not work on server side